# Usando vários arquivos js Vue no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, webpack

Galera estou usando o Laravel v5.5 para iniciar um projeto pessoal e vou utilizar o Vue.js, não achei um conteúdo muito didático na internet, como faço pra usar outros arquivos .js??

exemplo:
/js/login.js para o login
/js/dashboard.js para o dashboard

preciso configurar algo no webpack.mix.js? se sim, como fica? já rodei o npm install

Comment: Talvez isto ajude, https://medium.com/laravel-news/advanced-front-end-setup-with-vue-js-laravel-e9fbd7e89fe2

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas, uma resposta rápida seria para você importar esses .js em seu app.js, mas não sei se é só isso que você quer, então, segue uma estrutura bacana que adotei quando trabalho com vue.js no laravel:

**resources/assets/js/classes**
Ficam todas as classes de javascript que precisar, por exemplo:

- Form.js
- Utils.js
- Errors.js
- ...

Cada classe, é registrada globalmente dentro dela mesma:

- window.Form = Form;
- window.Utils = Utils;
- window.Errors = Errors;
- ...

Exemplo:

```
export default class Form
{

    constructor(data)
    {
       ...
    }

    reset()
    {       
       ...
    }

    data()
    {
       ...
    }

    submit(method, endPoint)
    {
       ...
    }

    onSuccess(data)
    {
        ...
    }

    onFail(error)
    {
       ...
    }

}

window.Form = Form;
```

No **resources/assets/js/app.js** ocorre o import dessas classes:

- import Form from './classes/Form';
- import Utils from './classes/Utils';
- import Errors from './classes/Errors';
- ...

Ao mesmo tempo que, no **app.js** o Vue.js é instanciado junto com seus componentes, que ficam em **resources/assets/js/components**, exemplo:

```
Vue.component('menu-row', require('./components/MenuRow.vue'));
Vue.component('menu-form', require('./components/MenuForm.vue'));

// Root instance
const app = new Vue({
    el : '#app'
});
```

Assim você tem liberdade de criar suas classes em javascript, e utiliza-las nos componentes do vue.js tranquilamente